# HTTP Response Codes

Tags: data-request, api, internet

For a data visualization, I'm looking for [http response codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). There are many sources of this dataset, **but** I'm looking for

- machine readable (JSON preferred)
- reliably updated (so that my dataviz is always updated as well)
- reliably hosted (so I can use the file as a web-service)
- official (from some consortium or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible "official" source is from the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)

https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml

Formats:

- [XML](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml)
- [HTML](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml)
- [TXT](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.txt)
- [CSV](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes-1.csv)